# Google map disappears if page is scrolled up in Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I have a problem with google map on this [page](http://mysql5.php5.sk/inna/www/) in Chrome.
Please reload the page scroll down and then up. When you are at absolute top, scroll to the map. You should see blank area (also blank form below). I dont understant what happens. Console does not show any error. If you will drag the map area or if you try to find the map in debuger the map will display. When I remove the map from the site, everything works fine(form is ok...). Can somebody help me please?

Init script is quite simple:

```
// Google map /////////////////////////////////

function initializeMap() {

  var newark = new google.maps.LatLng(48.896182, 18.043555);
  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(48.895790, 18.041800),
      new google.maps.LatLng(48.900000, 18.045555));

  var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: newark,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            //style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  mark = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      '/inna/www/images/map_arrow.png',
      imageBounds
  );
  mark.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);
```

Comment: I don't know what's happening. The map works for me.

Comment: It is not possible. Did you open it in Chrome?

Comment: Yep. I opened it in Chrome.

Comment: @Čamo: which OS and chrome-version do you use?

Comment: I am on WXP. Realy nobody have the problem with it?

Comment: No I tried that on Windows XP SP 3 with Chrome Version `41.0.2272.118 m`; may be you can try `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` somewhere....

Comment: It is not a solution or i don't understant what you mean. It makes none sense.